# How to get URL parameter and redirect after

Tags: php, html, url, redirect, forum

Please I need help with how to write php code to get a URL parameter from and redirect to another page after. My URL looks something like this http://mywebsite.com/login.php?referrer=forum

The parameter I am interested in is the referrer=forum

I need this because i am trying to integrate a forum into my website which i am almost done with except for the single sign on(SSO) feature which allows the forum to use the register and login system i have already created for my website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<?php
// get parameter from URL params
$referrer = $_GET['referrer'];

// redirect to another URL, including the referrer above
header('Location: http://someotherwebsite.com/?referrer=' . $referrer);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store that parameter value in variable and pass in the link or you can use Session to use that variable across the multiple page.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['referrer'] = $_GET['referrer'];
?>
```

And then in second page just use it from the session

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    echo $_SESSION['referrer']; // use it as per your requirement
?>
```

Comment: $_SESSIONS will only work on the same domain, same subdomain... i think the user wants to redirect to another site.

Comment: @PhilPoore Thanks for the answer i have tried your suggestns & its still not working.... d forum i used is codoforum https://codoforum.com/documentation/implementing-codoforum-sso & i developed d login system using dreamweaver and it looks like this  ....  if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl']; 
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  elseif ($_SESSION['referrer'] === 'codoforum') {
      
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }

Comment: @JayminPanchal    Thanks for the answer i have tried your suggestns & its still not working.... d forum i used is codoforum https://codoforum.com/documentation/implementing-codoforum-sso & i developed d login system using dreamweaver and it looks like this  ....  if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl']; 
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  elseif ($_SESSION['referrer'] === 'codoforum') {
      
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }

Comment: please update your question with the above code and try to reword your question to be more specific what your after :P